# Mongoose - query by date does not return results

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to query Mongo with Mongoose with the following query:

```
let lastTimes = moment().subtract(40, 'days');
Flight.find({lut: {"$gt": lastTimes.toDate().toISOString()}})
```

The call: `lastTimes.toDate().toISOString()` returns "2018-01-22T09:29:38.729Z".
Here is an example object from the database:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5a859a1b1b7517000ef1946d"
},
"airlineCode": "VS",
"flightNumber": "25",
"created": {
    "$date": "2018-02-15T14:32:59.771Z"
},
"lut": {
    "$date": "2018-02-16T03:54:19.566Z"
}
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Please advise.

Comment: Try with `ISODate` to compare dates:
 `"$gt" : ISODate(lastTimes.toDate().toISOString())`

Comment: @HassanImam, I get an error "ISODate is not defined".

Comment: Try passing the simple date object, `ISODate` is a part of MongoDB

Comment: @HassanImam, I tried to pass 'lastTimes.toDate()' but also did not get any results

Comment: Try this query `Flight.find({'lut.$date': {"$gt": lastTimes.toDate()}})`

Comment: @HassanImam, still nothing.

Comment: Maybe try this `Flight.find({'lut.$date': {"$gt": lastTimes.toDate().toISOString()}})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166147/discussion-between-david-faiz-and-hassan-imam).